# For OkHttp, Does SSLSocketFactory use SocketFactory first?

Tags: android, http, networking, okhttp

I'm currently wanting to use ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback on Android, hoping to direct all REST calls to a "good" network with OkHttp. While looking at OkHttp's API, should I implement both SocketFactory and SSLSocketFactory to redirect calls to another network, or will SocketFactory be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, OkHttp always starts with a regular socket first. You can see this in [RealConnection.java](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/10360b88efa801bf6b67d19423565c18a9f1a177/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/internal/connection/RealConnection.java#L231).

Because connecting to an HTTPS server over an HTTP proxy requires a plaintext `CONNECT` request, it’s unlikely that any other approach would work.